# Variables changed in functions are not changing outside the function in Node

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've been having trouble with this for a while. This is my debug build of google sign in permissions.

```
socket.on("signindata",(data)=>{
    handleUser(data, (husr)=>{
      userfile = husr
      for (let i = 0;usergroups.length;i++) {
        console.log(i)
        if (usergroups[i].id == husr.perms[0]){
          socket.perm = usergroups[i]
          console.log(socket.perm)
          break
        }
      }
    })
})
```

Whenever I try to call socket.perm outside of the function, it returns undefined.

What am I doing wrong?